# How to Prevent Truncation of RSS Feed Items in Drupal 7?

Tags: feeds

I'm using Drupal 7 and the Feeds module to import one RSS feed. When viewing imported feed items under "View Items" tab all feed items having more than one paragraph are being truncated after the first paragraph[...]. I've set Feed Items content type custom display setting to "Show full content" and it made no difference...content is still truncated after first paragraph.

I would like to configure the View page of feed items to show a list of teasers with "read more" links pointing to each feed item's full content on a separate page/node.

Not sure how to configure to accomplish this.

Thanks in advance for any tips or suggestions.